# ZoomedOutView with disabled keys

Tags: xaml, windows-runtime

Does anybody know how to reproduce the ZoomedOutView  like in the following picture:

[Picture http://img690.imageshack.us/img690/2981/84364982.png](http://img690.imageshack.us/img690/2981/84364982.png)

I have a solution that probably works but I think we can do that differently.

My solution :

- Add all the keys in the binded and grouped collection
- Create a converter Int32 to Booleab
- Bind the enabled property to Group.Values.Count and apply the converter
- Modify the GridViewItem style to change the Background property

Is there an easier way to do that ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those steps sound about right and should be the most straightforward way to get to what you want.

One place you might run into trouble is with getting the Group counts. Depending on what you're using for grouping you may get an `IEnumerable` with only the `Count()` extension method available and not a real `Count` property that would be bindable. This would be the case if you were using LINQ's `GroupBy` for example.